# JS calculator doesn't output or run the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I tried to build a simple calculator like this:
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/87a7e7193bea6b3f89d48554a128d6d42d50203b.png

Seems like it doesn't work, probably I didn't write the code correctly at all. I would be glad if you can correct me how to do this kind of simple calculator it will help me a lot.
thanks again!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>HomePage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
  </div>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Number1" id="num1">
    <select name="operator" id="dropW">
      <option value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="*">*</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
      <option value="%">%</option>
      <option value="^">^</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Number2" id="num2">
  </form>
  <button onclick="calc()">Calc</button>
  <p id="answer">answer</p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
function calc() {
  var field1 = document.getElementById("num1").Value;
  var field2 = document.getElementById("num2").Value;
  var field3 = document.getElementById("drop").Value;
  field1 = parseFloat(field1);
  field2 = parseFloat(field2);
  if (field3 == "+") {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (field1 + field2);
  }

  if (field3 == "-") {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (field1 - field2);
  }

  if (field3 == "*") {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (field1 * field2);
  }

  if (field3 == "/") {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (field1 / field2);
  }

  if (field3 == "%") {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (field1 % field2);
  }

  if (field3 == "^") {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (field1 ^ field2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Many little typos.... case matters Value !== value Use your console. Wrong id.  And submit buttons submit, so you need to cancel the click.

Comment: console.log(field1, field2, field3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summaries the changes mentioned in comments above

- As @epascarello mentioned, you need to change the `.Value` property to `.value` as properties are case sensative in Javascript.
- As @Nathan mentioned, you need to change `id="dropW"` to `id="drop"`.
- As @Terry mentioned, you need to change (field1^field2) to Math.pow(field1, field2) as the `^` operator is actually used for [bitwise operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Past these changes, everything should work as intended. If not, it may be an issue with how you're loading your Javascript.

```js
function calc ()
{
    /* Switched Value to value as properties are case sensative */
    var field1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var field2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    /* Switched dropW to drop as mentioned in a previous comment */
    var field3 = document.getElementById("drop").value;
    
    console.log(field1, field2, field3)
    
    field1 = parseFloat(field1);
    field2 = parseFloat(field2);
    if(field3 == "+")
    {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =(field1+field2);
    }

    if(field3 == "-")
    {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =(field1-field2);
    }

    if(field3 == "*")
    {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =(field1*field2);
    }

    if(field3 == "/")
    {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =(field1/field2);
    }

    if(field3 == "%")
    {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =(field1%field2);
    }

    if(field3 == "^")
    {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = Math.pow(field1, field2);
    }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
    </div>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Number1" id="num1">
        <select name="operator" id="drop">
                <option value="+">+</option>
                <option value="-">-</option>
                <option value="*">*</option>
                <option value="/">/</option>
                <option value="%">%</option>
                <option value="^">^</option>
              </select>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Number2" id="num2">
    </form>
    <button onclick="calc()">Calc</button>
    <p id="answer">answer</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, `(field1^field2)` does not work. You need to use `Math.pow(field1, field2)`

Comment: @Terry Thanks, I completely overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on `script.js:5`

`script.js:5` is `var field3 = document.getElementById("drop").Value;`.

Where is the element with ID `drop`? :)

Comment: My mistake. I wrote dropw instead of drop. I changed it but it doesn't give me the calculation. Its do nothing

Comment: nothing. I click the button and it does nothing.no errors in console .